# Is is it possible to set an expiry time on the cached version of each node individually in a Drupal 6 website?

Tags: 6, caching

Is is it possible to set an expiry time on the cached version of each node individually in a Drupal 6 website? The expiry time could be based on any factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Scheduler](http://drupal.org/project/scheduler).

From the project page:

> This module allows nodes to be published and unpublished on specified dates.

What are some examples of factors for expiry date?

Comment: One factor could be the published date. Older nodes could be cached longer than newer nodes. The other could be the type of node. Page nodes could be cached longer than story nodes. I am looking forward to the first one thought. Thanks for the update.

Comment: By the way I just realized a big blunder. I meant to ask if  we could put an expiry time on the 'cached verion' of a node

Comment: It's not really clear what is your question - what do you want to achieve (paraphrase)? What modules are you using now?